# Saving a CSV file using CHCSVWriter

Tags: objective-c, ios, csv, nsfilemanager

I'm attempting to write a large CSV file, from a core data managed object to the apps documents directory using CHCSVWriter.

While it seems runs fine, the cvs file doesn't seem to exist once completed.

```
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filename = @"productFileExport.csv";
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:documentsDirectory, filename, nil]];    

    CHCSVWriter *cvsExport = [[CHCSVWriter alloc] initWithCSVFile:[fileURL absoluteString] atomic:NO];

    for (Product *prod in fetchedObjects) {
        [cvsExport writeLineOfFields:prod.code, prod.barcode, prod.name, prod.size, prod.casesize, nil];
    }
    [cvsExport closeFile];
```

I believe it to be an issue with the filename i've tried changing the initWithCVSFile: from [fileURL absoluteString] to [fileURL path] and [fileURL description] with no luck.
Also if i change atomic to YES it get the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSFileManager
>   moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:]: destination path is nil'

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the `cvsExport writeLineOfFields` the first object being passed was nil so nothing was getting written to the file.

also the `initWithCVSFile:` required `[fileURL path]` to be passed to it.